# Access https page in Common Lisp error

Tags: ssl, common-lisp

Right now when I am trying in Common Lisp to connect to an https site with [dexador](https://github.com/fukamachi/dexador) I get this error:

```
   SSL verify error: 20 X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
       [Condition of type CL+SSL:SSL-ERROR-VERIFY]
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I get this problem also, I do not get a good solution but it works. It seems that it is a issue:

```
CL-USER> (dex:get "https://www.google.com")
; Evaluation aborted on #<CL+SSL:SSL-ERROR-VERIFY {1006991FA3}>.
```

This issue is related [here](https://github.com/fukamachi/dexador/issues/29) it seems that is a problem with the CAcerts file. that doesn't have the correct CA authorities and cl+ssl:

> It may be related to SSLv3 is disabled by default in CL+SSL, so
>   Dexador tries to connect with TLS 1.2.
>
> SSL verification of Dexador is quite new and not mature at all. It
>   would be better to specify the verification setting in Dexador easily,
>   however, using cl+ssl:make-context to allow SSLv3 is the only option
>   for now, I guess.

So for now you have two options:

1) make it insecure

```
CL-USER> (dex:get "https://www.google.com" :insecure t)
"<!doctype html><html itemscope=\"\" itemtype=\"http://schema.org
```

....
peer: 216.58.211.227:443" {1004DD8003}>>

use the path for ca file usually at /etc/ssl/cert.pem

```
CL-USER> (dex:get "https://www.google.com" :ca-path "/etc/ssl/oldcert.pem")
"<!doctype html><html itemscope=\"\" itemtype=\"http://schema.org/WebPage\" lang=\"es\"><head><meta content=\"Google.es permite acceder a la información mundial en castellano, catalán, gallego, euskara e inglés.\" name=\"description\"><meta content=\"noodp\" name=\"robots\"><meta content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" http-equiv=\"Content-Type\"><meta content=\"/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png\" itemprop=\"image\"><title>Google</title><script>(function(){window.google={kEI:'zwrdWM3qM4X9ae68n9gF',kEXPI:'1351891,1352993,1353040,1353108,1353148,3700248,3700347,3700405,3700407,4029815,4031109,4032677,4036527,4038012,4039268,4043492,4045841,4048347,4065786,4066196,4071842,4072364,4072776,4076096,4076999,4078430,4079444,4081039,4081165,4083046,4083863,4088341,4090550,4090553,4090806,4091420,4092183,4092245,4092628,4092827,4092934,4093498,4093792,4094055,4094251,4094544,4094837,4095574,4095787,4095910,4095998,4096324,4097129,4097153,4097203,4097866,4097922,4097929,4098047,4098721,4098728,4098752,4100150,4100169,4100380,4100825,4100859,4101375,4101651,4101681,4102020,4102099,4102411,4102658,4102753,4102987,4103060,4103183,4103238,4103474,4103987,4103999,4104006,4104290,4105239,4105317,8300497,8503585,8507380,8508229,8508707,8508931,8509037,8509373,8511650,10200083,10200096,19001720,19001764,19001922,41027342',authuser:0,kscs:'c9c918f0_24'};google.kHL='es';})();(function(){google.lc=[];google.li=0;google.getEI=function(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute(\"eid\")));)a=a.parentNode;return b||google.kEI};google.getLEI=function(a){for(var b=null;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute(\"leid\")));)a=a.parentNode;return b};google.https=function(){return\"https:\"==window.location.protocol};google.ml=function(){return null};google.wl=function(a,b){try{google.ml(Error(a),!1,b)}catch(c){}};google.time=function(){return(new Date).getTime()};google.log=function(a,b,c,d,g){a=google.logUrl(a,b,c,d,g);if(\"\"!=a){b=new Image;var e=google.lc,f=google.li;e[f]=b;b.onerror=b.onload=b.onabort=function(){delete e[f]};window.google&&window.google.vel&&window.google.vel.lu&&window.google.vel.lu(a);b.src=a;google.li=f+1}};google.logUrl=function(a,b,c,d,g){var e=\"\",f=google.ls||\"\";c||-1!=b.search(\"&ei=\")||(e=\"&ei=\"+google.getEI(d),-1==b.search(\"&lei=\")&&(d=google.getLEI(d))&&(e+=\"&lei=\"+d));a=c||\"/\"+(g||\"gen_204\")+\"?atyp=i&ct=\"+a+\"&cad=\"+b+e+f+\"&zx=\"+google.time();/^http:/i.test(a)&&google.https()&&(google.ml(Error(\"a\"),!1,{src:a,glmm:1}),a=\"\");return a};google.y={};google.x=function(a,b){google.y[a.id]=[a,b];return!1};google.lq=[];google.load=function(a,b,c){google.lq.push([[a],b,c])};google.loadAll=function(a,b){google.lq.push([a,b])};}).call(this);var a=window.location,b=a.href.indexOf(\"#\");if(0<=b){var c=a.href.substring(b+1);/(^|&)q=/.test(c)&&-1==c.indexOf(\"#\")&&a.replace(\"/search?\"+c.replace(/(^|&)fp=[^&]*/g,\"\")+\"&cad=h\")};</script><style>#gbar,#guser{font-size:13px;padding-top:1px !important;}#gbar{height:22px}#guser{padding-bottom:7px !important;text-align:right}.gbh,.gbd{border-top:1px solid #c9d7f1;font-size:1px}.gbh{height:0;position:absolute;top:24px;width:100%}@media all{.gb1{height:22px;margin-right:.5em;vertical-align:top}#gbar{float:left}}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline !important}a.gb1,a.gb4{color:#00c !important}.gbi .gb4{color:#dd8e27 !important}.gbf .gb4{color:#900 !important}
</style><style>body,td,a,p,.h{font-family:arial,sans-serif}body{margin:0;overflow-y:scroll}#gog{padding:3px 8px 0}td{line-height:.8em}.gac_m td{line-height:17px}form{margin-bottom:20px}.h{color:#36c}.q{color:#00c}.ts td{padding:0}.ts{border-collapse:collapse}em{font-weight:bold;font-style:normal}.lst{height:25px;width:496px}.gsfi,.lst{font:18px arial,sans-serif}.gsfs{font:17px arial,sans-serif}.ds{display:inline-box;display:inline-block;margin:3px 0 4px;margin-left:4px}input{font-family:inherit}a.gb1,a.gb2,a.gb3,a.gb4{color:#11c !important}body{background:#fff;color:black}a{color:#11c;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:active{text-decoration:underline}.fl a{color:#36c}a:visited{color:#551a8b}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline}a.gb3:hover{text-decoration:none}#ghead a.gb2:hover{color:#fff !important}.sblc{padding-top:5px}.sblc a{display:block;margin:2px 0;margin-left:13px;font-size:11px}.lsbb{background:#eee;border:solid 1px;border-color:#ccc #999 #999 #ccc;height:30px}.lsbb{display:block}.ftl,#fll a{display:inline-block;margin:0 12px}.lsb{background:url(/images/nav_logo229.png) 0 -261px repeat-x;border:none;color:#000;cursor:pointer;height:30px;margin:0;outline:0;font:15px arial,sans-serif;vertical-align:top}.lsb:active{background:#ccc}.lst:focus{outline:none}</style><script></script><link href=\"/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico\" rel=\"shortcut icon\"></head><body bgcolor=\"#fff\"><script>(function(){var src='/images/nav_logo229.png';var iesg=false;document.body.onload = function(){window.n && window.n();if (document.images){new Image().src=src;}
if (!iesg){document.f&&document.f.q.focus();document.gbqf&&document.gbqf.q.focus();}
}
})();</script><div id=\"mngb\"> <div id=gbar><nobr><b class=gb1>Búsqueda</b> <a class=gb1 href=\"https://www.google.es/imghp?hl=es&tab=wi\">Imágenes</a> <a class=gb1 href=\"https://maps.google.es/maps?hl=es&tab=wl\">Maps</a> <a class=gb1 href=\"https://play.google.com/?hl=es&tab=w8\">Play</a> <a class=gb1 href=\"https://www.youtube.com/?gl=ES&tab=w1\">YouTube</a> <a class=gb1 href=\"https://news.google.es/nwshp?hl=es&tab=wn\">Noticias</a> <a class=gb1 href=\"https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm\">Gmail</a> <a class=gb1 href=\"https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo\">Drive</a> <a class=gb1 style=\"text-decoration:none\" href=\"https://www.google.es/intl/es/options/\"><u>Más</u> &raquo;</a></nobr></div><div id=guser width=100%><nobr><span id=gbn class=gbi></span><span id=gbf class=gbf></span><span id=gbe></span><a href=\"http://www.google.es/history/optout?hl=es\" class=gb4>Historial web</a> | <a  href=\"/preferences?hl=es\" class=gb4>Configuración</a> | <a target=_top id=gb_70 href=\"https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=es&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.es/%3Fgfe_rd%3Dcr%26ei%3DzwrdWNy9H4LVXu2VpOAE\" class=gb4>Iniciar sesión</a></nobr></div><div class=gbh style=left:0></div><div class=gbh style=right:0></div> </div><center><br clear=\"all\" id=\"lgpd\"><div id=\"lga\"><div style=\"padding:28px 0 3px\"><div style=\"height:110px;width:276px;background:url(/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_white_background_color_272x92dp.png) no-repeat\" title=\"Google\" align=\"left\" id=\"hplogo\" onload=\"window.lol&&lol()\"><div style=\"color:#777;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;position:relative;top:70px;left:218px\" nowrap=\"\">Espa&ntilde;a</div></div></div><br></div><form action=\"/search\" name=\"f\"><table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr valign=\"top\"><td width=\"25%\">&nbsp;</td><td align=\"center\" nowrap=\"\"><input name=\"ie\" value=\"ISO-8859-1\" type=\"hidden\"><input value=\"es\" name=\"hl\" type=\"hidden\"><input name=\"source\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"hp\"><input name=\"biw\" type=\"hidden\"><input name=\"bih\" type=\"hidden\"><div class=\"ds\" style=\"height:32px;margin:4px 0\"><input style=\"color:#000;margin:0;padding:5px 8px 0 6px;vertical-align:top\" autocomplete=\"off\" class=\"lst\" value=\"\" title=\"Buscar con Google\" maxlength=\"2048\" name=\"q\" size=\"57\"></div><br style=\"line-height:0\"><span class=\"ds\"><span class=\"lsbb\"><input class=\"lsb\" value=\"Buscar con Google\" name=\"btnG\" type=\"submit\"></span></span><span class=\"ds\"><span class=\"lsbb\"><input class=\"lsb\" value=\"Voy a tener suerte\" name=\"btnI\" onclick=\"if(this.form.q.value)this.checked=1; else top.location='/doodles/'\" type=\"submit\"></span></span></td><td class=\"fl sblc\" align=\"left\" nowrap=\"\" width=\"25%\"><a href=\"/advanced_search?hl=es&amp;authuser=0\">Búsqueda avanzada</a><a href=\"/language_tools?hl=es&amp;authuser=0\">Herramientas del idioma</a></td></tr></table><input id=\"gbv\" name=\"gbv\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"1\"></form><div id=\"gac_scont\"></div><div style=\"font-size:83%;min-height:3.5em\"><br><div id=\"prm\"><style>.szppmdbYutt__middle-slot-promo{font-size:small;margin-bottom:32px}.szppmdbYutt__middle-slot-promo a._uFi{display:inline-block;text-decoration:none}.szppmdbYutt__middle-slot-promo img{border:none;margin-right:5px;vertical-align:middle}.szppmdbYutt__middle-slot-promo ._vFi{color:red}</style><div class=\"szppmdbYutt__middle-slot-promo r-itJmcvDa5V20\" jsl=\"$t t-Gza07Ho9En4;$x 0;\" data-ved=\"0ahUKEwiNjuixrf7SAhWFfhoKHW7eB1sQnIcBCAQ\">Recorre los confines del mundo. <a class=\"_XIi\" href=\"https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.google.com/maps/%4061.017504,-45.299466,3a,75y,248.21h,81.91t/data%3D!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sxRh_03mgvd7k4DYZhLy_fA!2e0!7i13312!8i6670&amp;source=hpp&amp;id=19001922&amp;ct=3&amp;usg=AFQjCNGSMFzu6dYrNjwBD6tC2CU6qUF4tA&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiNjuixrf7SAhWFfhoKHW7eB1sQ8IcBCAU\" rel=\"nofollow\">Explora Groenlandia</a> en Google Maps.</div></div><div id=\"als\"><style>#als{font-size:small;margin-bottom:24px}#_eEe{display:inline-block;line-height:28px;}#_eEe a{padding:0 3px;}._lEe{display:inline-block;margin:0 2px;white-space:nowrap}._PEe{display:inline-block;margin:0 2px}</style><div id=\"_eEe\">Google.es también en: <a href=\"/url?q=https://www.google.es/setprefs%3Fsig%3D0_4urS_u8UYjdxr9RWPRUbF0f5UVE%253D%26hl%3Dca%26source%3Dhomepage&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiNjuixrf7SAhWFfhoKHW7eB1sQ2ZgBCAc&amp;usg=AFQjCNHFNrDxel2PpypWfm8Q8S_Hma4dBA\">català</a>  <a href=\"/url?q=https://www.google.es/setprefs%3Fsig%3D0_4urS_u8UYjdxr9RWPRUbF0f5UVE%253D%26hl%3Dgl%26source%3Dhomepage&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiNjuixrf7SAhWFfhoKHW7eB1sQ2ZgBCAg&amp;usg=AFQjCNFWHfz2qcwwnr3ukNqO0e5E-_K25A\">galego</a>  <a href=\"/url?q=https://www.google.es/setprefs%3Fsig%3D0_4urS_u8UYjdxr9RWPRUbF0f5UVE%253D%26hl%3Deu%26source%3Dhomepage&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiNjuixrf7SAhWFfhoKHW7eB1sQ2ZgBCAk&amp;usg=AFQjCNF2MZ0hnDNRZugUR8OTrCA7dp50Ag\">euskara</a> </div></div></div><span id=\"footer\"><div style=\"font-size:10pt\"><div style=\"margin:19px auto;text-align:center\" id=\"fll\"><a href=\"/intl/es/ads/\">Programas de publicidad</a><a href=\"http://www.google.es/intl/es/services/\">Soluciones Empresariales</a><a href=\"https://plus.google.com/115920203808848871228\" rel=\"publisher\">+Google</a><a href=\"/intl/es/about.html\">Todo acerca de Google</a><a href=\"https://www.google.es/setprefdomain?prefdom=US&amp;sig=__JEQfki8NLT51lY27hVKTcD7x60I%3D\" id=\"fehl\">Google.com</a></div></div><p style=\"color:#767676;font-size:8pt\">&copy; 2017 - <a href=\"/intl/es/policies/privacy/\">Privacidad</a> - <a href=\"/intl/es/policies/terms/\">Condiciones</a></p></span></center><script>(function(){window.google.cdo={height:0,width:0};(function(){var a=window.innerWidth,b=window.innerHeight;if(!a||!b)var c=window.document,d=\"CSS1Compat\"==c.compatMode?c.documentElement:c.body,a=d.clientWidth,b=d.clientHeight;a&&b&&(a!=google.cdo.width||b!=google.cdo.height)&&google.log(\"\",\"\",\"/client_204?&atyp=i&biw=\"+a+\"&bih=\"+b+\"&ei=\"+google.kEI);}).call(this);})();</script><div id=\"xjsd\"></div><div id=\"xjsi\"><script>(function(){function c(b){window.setTimeout(function(){var a=document.createElement(\"script\");a.src=b;document.getElementById(\"xjsd\").appendChild(a)},0)}google.dljp=function(b,a){google.xjsu=b;c(a)};google.dlj=c;}).call(this);(function(){window.google.xjsrm=['mids'];})();if(google.y)google.y.first=[];if(!google.xjs){window._=window._||{};window._DumpException=window._._DumpException=function(e){throw e};if(google.timers&&google.timers.load.t){google.timers.load.t.xjsls=new Date().getTime();}google.dljp('/xjs/_/js/k\\x3dxjs.hp.en_US.q7EuCVIfdZw.O/m\\x3dsb_he,d/am\\x3dAAg/rt\\x3dj/d\\x3d1/t\\x3dzcms/rs\\x3dACT90oHF3pWF1nFj9p3M-bzcFbKqP3_GDw','/xjs/_/js/k\\x3dxjs.hp.en_US.q7EuCVIfdZw.O/m\\x3dsb_he,d/am\\x3dAAg/rt\\x3dj/d\\x3d1/t\\x3dzcms/rs\\x3dACT90oHF3pWF1nFj9p3M-bzcFbKqP3_GDw');google.xjs=1;}google.pmc={\"sb_he\":{\"agen\":true,\"cgen\":true,\"client\":\"heirloom-hp\",\"dh\":true,\"dhqt\":true,\"ds\":\"\",\"fl\":true,\"host\":\"google.es\",\"isbh\":28,\"jam\":0,\"jsonp\":true,\"lm\":true,\"msgs\":{\"cibl\":\"Borrar búsqueda\",\"dym\":\"Quizás quisiste decir:\",\"lcky\":\"Voy a tener suerte\",\"lml\":\"Más información\",\"oskt\":\"Herramientas de introducción de texto\",\"psrc\":\"Esta búsqueda se ha eliminado de tu \\u003Ca href=\\\"/history\\\"\\u003Ehistorial web\\u003C/a\\u003E.\",\"psrl\":\"Eliminar\",\"sbit\":\"Buscar por imagen\",\"srch\":\"Buscar con Google\"},\"nds\":true,\"ovr\":{},\"pq\":\"\",\"refpd\":true,\"rfs\":[],\"sbpl\":24,\"sbpr\":24,\"scd\":10,\"sce\":5,\"stok\":\"mhB5xRw_UP_UKC2jJd_Cpa-6ZKQ\"},\"d\":{},\"YFCs/g\":{}};google.y.first.push(function(){if(google.med){google.med('init');google.initHistory();google.med('history');}});if(google.j&&google.j.en&&google.j.xi){window.setTimeout(google.j.xi,0);}
</script></div></body></html>"
200
#<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUAL :COUNT 13 {10075921A3}>
#<QURI.URI.HTTP:URI-HTTPS https://www.google.es/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=zwrdWNy9H4LVXu2VpOAE>
#<CL+SSL::SSL-STREAM for #<FD-STREAM for "socket 192.168.43.17:53430, peer: 172.217.20.67:443" {1007458073}>>
```

Or activate SSlv3 in a cl+ssl context

Comment: Where does the cert file come from? I was wondering if this is a self-signed cert or your own personal cert, or do you have to get a cert from the website you’re scraping?

Comment: It was genereated by default in your computer,this is the content beginning: ##
## Bundle of CA Root Certificates
##
## Certificate data from Mozilla as of: Wed Jan 18 04:12:05 2017 GMT
##
## This is a bundle of X.509 certificates of public Certificate Authorities
## (CA)